# adding map in xml slow down the app

Tags: android

As soon as I add a map into my layout XML, the activity will be loaded very slow. After a long time, it will jump to the activity and display the map. I'm fresh about this, any help will be good.

I found a web link that says I should try **delay load**. I understand it as it will go to the activity first and then load the map. But I'm not sure how to realize this.

Could anyone provide an example?

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:id="@+id/location_map"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rl_personaltrip_departure_times"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="200dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
             android:enabled="true"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:apiKey="@string/maps_api_key"
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write down this below code

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.preLoad();
```

Comment: k.if any query contact me on following link chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18781/room-for-ckpatel